# Firebase Hosting - how to get current json

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Hosting with Dynamic Links (I use my own domain as described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#manual).

The documentation says

> Note: You can check the deployed firebase.json content using the
>   Hosting REST API.

However, I'm not able to see that deployed firebase.json file in any way. I've tried using REST API, I was looking for those file in Google Cloud, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Visit: [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firebase/firebasehosting/v1beta1/firebasehosting.sites.releases.list)

```
Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0: On
parent: sites/your-project-id
```

Comment: That will show things like the rewrites config, so might be helpful for merging back updates, but it doesn't give the full firebase.json contents.